# How to load the symbols form a style file in Arcgis in .net SDK?

Tags: c#, .net, arcgis

Am new to the arcgis SDK and this is my very first application i have a .style file which contains all my symbols to use on my map how to change these symbols to  a bitmap so it could be seen in a C# application thanks

Comment: found any solution to your problem?

Comment: no i didnt haider am sorry